# understanding async behavior of use Effect hook working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

```
 const [count,setCount]=useState(5)
useEffect(()=>{

setCount(10)},[count])
```

In above code if i am updating state without async operation useEffect doesn't goes to infite loop.While in below code if i update sate through asysnc operation it goes to infite loop can some one tell me the behavior of useEffect in the case of async oeration?

```
const [count,setCount]=useState(5)
useEffect(()=>{
//some async operation
.then(response)=>{
setCount(response.data)}},[count])
```

Comment: Check if `response.data` is a Number. And check if response doesn't return new value every time you get it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because numbers are compared to values and objects by references. Each time async operation result in new object reference, hence `useEffect` triggers.

In case of number like `setCount(5)` will not trigger again as second time `5` is the same variable as previous.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a good question!

In the first snippet you were setting the count to 10, that value is not changing dynamically and hence it will change once and wait for the count to change again which will not happen over there, whereas in the second snippet once the async operation is completed it will update the `count` and because of this count update `useEffect` will be triggered again along with the async operation in it. So it goes into a recursive updation.

If you want, you can change the first snippet like this to see the recursive updation

```
setCount(count + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the catch of hooks and how they update state, if your previous state value and current state value is same then react functional component won't re-renders, so it is advisable if you are working with object type of state then always create new object or use spread operator for updating any property inside object while updating your state. In your case **setCount(10)** will always return a constant value of 10 so useEffect won't trigger infinite times as count is theoretically changed once from 5 to 10, but for an API request it will always returns an object with new reference so it'll create an infinite loop. You can also do **setCount(10)** inside your API result and it also won't trigger useEffect as count is basically never changed from 10 except from a change **5 to 10**.

Comment: FYI, this behaviour is mentioned in their docs if you read about hooks on their docs.